# C# get rid of Connection header in WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using the C# using the WebClient().

I was testing out what headers are sent, and I noticed that the following header is automatically added.

```
Connection : Keep-Alive
```

Is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score 16):

I had ran into the same issue this morning. Following on Jon Skeet's hint, it can be achieved by passing `HttpWebRequest` to `WebClient` by inheriting it:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Now sent headers will include `Connection : close`

Comment: Let me suggest an updated version since  C# has moved a little since ;-) 

`class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest wr)
            {
                wr.KeepAlive = false;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebClient` (it's *slightly* less convenient, but not by very much) and set the [`KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) property to `false`.

I haven't tested this - it's *possible* that it'll just change the value of the Connection header instead of removing it - but it's worth a try. The docs for the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.connection.aspx) property at least *suggest* that it only adds Keep-Alive.

Comment: One thing to note is that doing this doesn't *remove* the Connection header, although it does change it from "Connection: Keep-Alive" to "Connection: Close".