# WebClient is opening a new connection each time I download a file and all of them stay established

Tags: c#, http

I'm having a problem finding out how to close the connection made by `WebClient`. I create a new `WebClient` object and then call `DownloadFile` method a lot of times, however, it always creates a new connection for each call and those connections stay open (Established state), I can see in TCPView all the established connections.

What bugs me even more if when I dispose the `Webclient`, they stay established...?
How to force the connection to be closed after the download is done?

I already tried to derive WebClient and set keep alive manually to false, my app config allow enough connections as well.

```
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How many connections at maximum? Looks like keep-alive.

Comment: @usr even if it's keep-alive, shouldn't the connection be closed if the webclient is disposed?

Comment: .NET pools connections across object instances. This is normal. Again, how many?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer: you shouldn't need to close the connections manually. They are managed for you behind the scenes.

HTTP/1.1 connections are not closed as soon as the request completes in order that multiple requests to the same server are handled in a more timely and efficient manner (such as a web browser requesting multiple files from a single site). You shouldn't have to worry about this or close them down manually, as they'll timeout after a while. Is it causing an error?

If it is an issue, you could try inheriting from `WebClient` and overriding the `GetWebRequest` method to manually set `KeepAlive`, e.g.:

```
public class NoKeepAlivesWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

I'd also always suggest using the using pattern for `WebClient`:

```
using (var client = new NoKeepAlivesWebClient())
{
    // Some code
}
```

Finally, here's some RFC information about persistent connections in HTTP/1.1:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

and a friendlier Wikipedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

**Edit:**

Apologies. I see from your edited question that you've already tried something like the above, without success.

I was unable to reproduce your issue, however. I wrote a small program using the `NoKeepAlivesWebClient` and it successfully closed connections after they were used, according to TCPView.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Random test URLs
    var urls = new List<string> {
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx",
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.allowreadstreambuffering.aspx",
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.allowwritestreambuffering.aspx",
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.baseaddress.aspx",
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cachepolicy.aspx",
        "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx",
        "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "https://www.youtube.com/feed/UClTpDNIOtgfRkyT-AFGNWVw",
        "https://www.youtube.com/feed/UCj_UmpoD8Ph_EcyN_xEXrUQ",
        "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn-K7GIs62ENvdQe6ZZk9-w" };

    using (var client = new NoKeepAlivesWebClient())
    {
        // Save each URL to a Temp file
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName());
            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded: " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

There's another SO question here about the same issue:

[C# get rid of Connection header in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896207/c-sharp-get-rid-of-connection-header-in-webclient)

Comment: Thanks for all the infos, however I already tried exactly the same thing, no luck, I also tried to set Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout to 10 seconds but no effect as well. I need to close them because I'm using a lot of DownloadFile and after a while, I have like 200 etablished connections in tcpviews, that makes no sense

Comment: Sorry, @Lasty01 I didn't see your edit before posting my answer. I've edited it to add another option for you.

Comment: thanks again, but nothing seems to work... I tried this for now :

protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
 WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
 if (request is HttpWebRequest)
 {
  var webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
  webRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
  webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
  webRequest.Timeout = 10000;
  webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
 }

 return request;
}

Comment: @Lasty01 - I cannot reproduce the issue, I'm afraid. Are you sure you're downloading over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Well my bad, I found the error, I was calling OpenRead to get the filesize somewhere else, and I was disposing the webclient, but that was not enough, I had to store the stream returned by OpenRead in a var and dispose it explicitly, sorry for the confusion here, problem resolved, thanks all.

Comment: Overriding that method doesn't (no longer?) works...  `'NoKeepAlivesWebClient.GetWebRequest(System.Uri)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member`.

Comment: @im1dermike - I've updated the example, changing `public` to `protected` to get it working again.