# How to prevent HttpClient from sending the Connection header

Tags: c#, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

HttpClient includes this as 'Keep-Alive' by default. I've been able to set it to 'Close' using `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;` but how do I omit it altogether?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? The header determines how client and server communicate with each other.

Comment: `httpClient.KeepAlive = false` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @poke while trying to troubleshoot problems connecting to the poloniex trading api, I compared what I'm sending to what a working PHP app is sending and the inclusion of this header was the only difference I could see. I recognise that it's "meant" to be there, but I need to eliminate it as a potential cause of my issue.

Comment: @Rabban `'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'KeepAlive'`

Comment: Ok, ended up that my problem was unrelated, but I'm still curious whether or not this is possible.

Comment: This is a good question, and troubleshooting is a very legitimate reason, so why the downvote I have no idea. +1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've seen this asked before and to my knowledge no one ([not even the great Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/896482/62600)) has come up with a way to avoid sending the `Connection` header in the `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest` worlds without completely reinventing the wheel. It's happening somewhere very deep down in the weeds.

`ConnectionClose` is nullable, but setting it to null on both `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` AND `HttpRequestMethod.Headers` still results in a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header being sent.

To summarize:

- `HttpRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true` => `Connection: close`
- `HttpRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false` => `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- `HttpRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = null` => `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true` => `Connection: Keep-Alive`
- `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false` => `Connection: close`

(`HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive` is not nullable)