# How do I set the Connection header properly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, flurl

I am mirroring another request so I have an array with all the headers. I add each of them with `"url".WithHeaders(headersDictionary)`.

But when I test the request I get a second value in the `Connection` header.

The request is made like this:

```
req = ("https://httpbin.org/post").WithHeaders(headers).WithTimeout(60)
req.SendAsync(New Net.Http.HttpMethod("POST"), New Net.Http.StringContent(postData))
```

[image: screenshot of messed up connection header]

Are there other headers that may be automatically added or modified? Like `Expect100-Continue`, for example.

Comment: Flurl is built on top of HttpClient so it's subject to some of its behaviors/quirks. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411524/62600

Comment: @ToddMenier Is there a way to set `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive` from the `FlurlRequest`?